# What's the bottleneck in Spring r2dbc database connection?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

I've set up a [sample project](https://github.com/segevmalool/spring-samples/tree/main/spring-security-webflux-postgres) using spring boot, webflux, and r2dbc. I've been able to stream rows from a postgres db table to the client.

Is there a memory bottleneck on this server implementation (for storing the results of the query)? Do the rows stream through?

PS I'm not claiming any level of quality on this, I know pagination and so on would be essential, just wondering about how the db query interacts with the reactive framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pagination is not essential with R2DBC. If you have a lot of rows to process you can issue a single query instead of fetching batches. The driver uses back-pressure to allow flow control so it does not overwhelm your application. You could [read](https://gitter.im/R2DBC/r2dbc?at=5dd3aa94add5717a8835d709) here about how backpressure is applied on such queries.

Comment: I think this makes sense for a business process that must process all the rows, but to supply data to a front-end application, wouldn't it make sense to provide a paginated interface to minimize data transfer and localize data processing to the db instance?

Comment: @Segev Malool Absolutely. If you want to fetch a fixed amount of rows then use paganation.